# How to use array of scala.collection.immutable.List in java code

Tags: java, list, scala

I am new to scala and I need to write a java code that passes an array of scala.collection.immutable.List to a scala function. More specifically, I use a scala function in my java code that needs as an argument a `scala.collection.immutable.List<Tuple2<Object, Object>>[]`. The objects need to be `<Integer, Double>`. In java this is quite simple:

```
    java.util.List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>[] javaList = new ArrayList[335];
            for (int i = 0; i < 335; i++) { 
                javaList[i] = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>(); 
            } 
              for(int i=0; i<100;i++)
             {
                 for(int j=0; j<50;j++)
               {
                   javaList[i].add(new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(j, value(j)));
                }
             }
```

I need or to convert it from java to scala or to create a `scala.collection.immutable.List<Tuple2<Object, Object>>[]` and use it directly in my java code, but i have a hard time to find it. I use Java 8, scala 2.12.2 in a maven project.

Comment: An **Array** of **Lists** is a weird data structure.Anyways, the **Scala** standard library provides ways to tranforming **Java** collections** into **Scala** ones and vice verse. I would write a function in **Scala** that receives the **Java** input, transform it into the **Scala** one and then calls the scala function.

Comment: Array of Lists is less weird if `@varargs def f(vs: List[Int]*)`.

Comment: my problem is that i can not change the scala parameter in the function:  scala.collection.immutable.List<Tuple2<Object, Object>>[] so i need to find a way to give from java code this structure .

Comment: @vicangel The easiest way would be to add a new **Scala** function that receives a data structure easy to create from **Java** a do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what order of abomination I just committed, but:

```
class Target {
  @annotation.varargs
  def f(lists: List[(Int, Double)]*): Int = lists.map(_.map(_._1).sum).sum
}
```

then

```
$ javap Target
Compiled from "scalafunc.scala"
public class Target {
  public int f(scala.collection.immutable.List<scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>>...);
  public int f(scala.collection.immutable.Seq<scala.collection.immutable.List<scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>>>);
  public static final int $anonfun$f$2(scala.Tuple2);
  public static final int $anonfun$f$1(scala.collection.immutable.List);
  public Target();
  public static final java.lang.Object $anonfun$f$1$adapted(scala.collection.immutable.List);
  public static final java.lang.Object $anonfun$f$2$adapted(scala.Tuple2);
}
```

And interop with Scala 2.13:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import scala.Tuple2;
import static scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters.asScala;

public class j {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    // populate an array list of lists
    var javaList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 335; i++) {
      javaList.add(new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100;i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<50;j++) {
        javaList.get(i).add(new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(j, Double.valueOf(j)));
      }
    }
    // convert the elements to scala lists; the result happens to be an arraylist
    var arg = (ArrayList<scala.collection.immutable.List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>>) javaList.stream().map(vs -> asScala(vs).toList()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // we need an array of scala lists
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    var template = (scala.collection.immutable.List<Tuple2<Object, Object>>[]) Array.newInstance(scala.collection.immutable.List.class, arg.size());
    // extract the target array
    var fargs = arg.toArray(template);
    Target t = new Target();
    // call the varargs f
    var res = t.f(fargs);
    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

and I could

```
$ scalac scalafunc.scala 
$ javac -Xlint -cp .:/home/me/scala-2.13.1/lib/scala-library.jar j.java && java -cp .:/home/me/scala-2.13.1/lib/scala-library.jar j
122500
```

I didn't verify that result; I'm not entirely confident just because it compiled in Java.

Comment: I guess if you start with an array, you use `Arrays.asList(start).stream`.